# Integrate Android Paypal sdk or MPL

Tags: android, paypal, sdk, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Integrate Android Paypal for my application, however their are few question thats bugging me regarding the sdk.

For their latest paypal sdk https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK:

**A1)** Is there a way to set a orderId or something similar so my server know what my customer buy?

**A2)** If my app is not operate in US, am I able to use the full feature (paypal and credit card payment)?

**A3)** How do I disable the card reader and only allow user to key in their card number or is it possible at all?

For their paypal MPL sdk https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

**B1)** Currently getting "Please make sure all field have been entered" error message and error id 10004 on sand box while running the sample code. Any idea how to fix it or is it their server issue?

**B2)** Should I still use MPL when they trying to phase it out?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer all of these:

A1. The underlying REST API does not support this feature, though it is expected to be added soon.

A2. You can accept payments in any location and in any supported currency. Restrictions are only where the *merchant* account (e.g. your account) is opened, since each country's laws are slightly different. [This list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/) gives more detail.

A3. You cannot disable the card.io scanner. The idea is that it is easier to use, so can you help me understand the rationale for this request?

B. Please don't use the MPL. It's not maintained and has an inferior UI.

Comment: With your A1 + B it cripple Paypal sdk usefulness, since I won't be able to know why customer paying me. Do you have any work around to accomplish A1 or reliable info when they going to update their sdk to support it? As for A3, it doesn't work; unsure it's because I'm testing on sandbox. It would be great if I'm able to show the manual key-in with button lead to scanner.

Comment: will appreciate answering B1 even though the solution might not be permanent, thanks

Comment: I've some queries regarding paypal future payments, could you please me?